# Setting the display on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I installed Ubuntu and it automatically configured the display. I am using Dell 16" CRT monitor. I can see the display settings configured to 1024x768 resolution. But the display on Ubuntu is quite bigger as compared to Windows XP on the same resolution. It is not showing more higher resolution options.

I want to make the appearance small so that I can see more things on the screen.

Comment: Please add some additional information about your system, f.e. what graphiccard you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I got your question right.... is there a **problem with the graphic card** that supports higher resolutions than 1024x768 but ubuntu does not give this option, or you are fine with the resolution but **would like icons and text to use less pixels**, so that you can put more of that on the screen?

If it is the first case, than an easy workaround is to use the proprietary graphic drivers (from System / Administration / Hardware drivers).

If it is the second case, than you have a few settings available from System / Preferences / Appearance, where you can choose different themes, fonts, icon sets, etc...

You can also browse plenty of gnome themes [here](http://www.gnome-look.org/) and check if there's any that meets your needs.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

However, you can still use xorg.conf if you require some special fine-tuning. But it is no more required.